# Hide lines in Sublime Text

Tags: debugging, logging, hide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I use Sublime Text for reading program logs and sometimes logs can be very verbose !

I wonder if there is a trick/add-on in Sublime Text that can hide some verbose lines (based on regexp for example) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this if you create a new syntax definition `.tmLanguage` file for your logs, and include the `foldingStartMarker` and `foldingStopMarker` keys. These files are XML-based, and the folding markers are defined by regular expressions, ranging from the straightforward (from SCSS):

```xml
<key>foldingStartMarker</key>
<string>\{\s*$</string>
<key>foldingStopMarker</key>
<string>^\s*\}</string>
```

to the complex (from Python):

```xml
<key>foldingStartMarker</key>
<string>^\s*(def|class)\s+([.a-zA-Z0-9_ &lt;]+)\s*(\((.*)\))?\s*:|\{\s*$|\(\s*$|\[\s*$|^\s*"""(?=.)(?!.*""")</string>
<key>foldingStopMarker</key>
<string>^\s*$|^\s*\}|^\s*\]|^\s*\)|^\s*"""\s*$</string>
```

If you can divine some regexes for your log files, then all the magic and convenience of code folding is yours. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your idea ! But at where I work, logs change its format quite often (and along with them the useless infos) it would be better if we can choose to hide lines on the fly, i.e. without modifying a .tmLanguage file